# Importing data from excel to multiple tables in Sql Server database

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I have an excel sheet where in the data looks similar to the table below :

```
EmployeeName    Manager Name
E1              M1
E2              M2
E3              M3
E4              M1
```

I need to export this into a database which has two separate table for employee and manager.

Sql tables which I am exporting to has structure like this:

```
Create Table Manager (Manager_Id int Primary Key Identity(1,1), 
                      ManagerName nvarchar(50))

Create Table Employee (EmployeeID int Primary Key Identity(1,1) ,
                       EmployeeName nvarchar(50), 
                       Manager_Id int)
```

ManagerId is a foreign reference in the employee table.

Since I need Manager Table before the Employee table, I successfully imported the manager data first using SQL Server Import and Export wizard.

My next step was to import data into the employee table.This is where the problem comes in.
Now, I want manager Id from a table sitting in the Sql Server database and the employee names from the excel sheet. I though there must be a way in the Import and Export wizard in the Sql Statement option to write a query which can refer to both excel and the sql table but I get an error "This is not a query"

Is there a better way of importing data to multiple tables?

Comment: What is your query which is giving you the error?  Are you trying to create a table with employee name and manager name?

Comment: @Robert: Excel Sheet has just two columns one for the employee name and other for the manager name now this is to be moved to two tables in Sql Server, one Employee and other manager.

Comment: that's what I used on the  "Provide a source query " screen in Sql Server import and export wizard after importing manager data in the manager table :  
Select s1.EmployeeName,
(select manager_id from test.dbo.manager m where s1.managername = m.managername) as ManagerName

 from `sheet1$` s1

Comment: I thought I can refer to both excel sheet data and the Sql Server data together in this window

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of importing the Employee data to the Employee table, import it into a Temp table on SQL server. Then you will be able to write a query which retrieves the employee name from the Temp table, joins it to the Manager table and then inserts into the real Employee table.

Answer (score 0):

There are many solutions to this, but if the data set is relatively small, I'd just do this in Excel:

1. Separate the data into Manager and Employee tabs (leave both columns in the Employee tab)
2. Add some ID columns to both tabs.
3. Use the vlookup function on the Manager's name to find the relevant Manager IDs for each employee.  Copy&PasteValues to get rid of the functions you just made.
4. Use the import wizard to get both tables into SQL Server.

Comment: SQL tables I am exporting to has Identity Column so I am not sure if I can use your solution

Comment: I see your point. This won't work then.  Good luck on your solution.